# Obtener id de div en forma dinámica con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Hola estoy generando una lista en forma dinámica con PHP (Laravel) y jQuery, que viene desde una consulta de una base de datos.

Por cada lista, se selecciona una opción, y se hace una consulta a la base de datos. Su resultado es impreso en un `<div>` que es generado de forma dinámica y que corresponde a la lista en particular.

Lo que no he podido lograr es capturar el valor id del `<div>` dinámico con jQuery, y así poder imprimir el resultado en la sección que corresponde a la lista.

En la consola generalmente me aparece como `undefined` o no me aparece nada. Si en el script le doy el id específico en forma manual, entonces sí me lo imprime.

La verdad si tengo otra forma de lograr lo que quiero hacer, pero me gustaría intentar con este método dinámico ya que me ahorraría mucho código.

Le dejo parte del código, agradecería la ayuda.

Parte HTML/Laravel:

```
@foreach($carreras as $i => $carr)
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h4>{{$facultades[$i]->nombre}}</h4>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control carreras_list_{{$i}}" name="">
      @foreach($carr as $j => $c)
      <option value="{{$c->carreraid}}">{{$c->carrera}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="tag{{$i}}" class="col-md-12"></div>
@endforeach
```

Parte JS:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', '.graficos-carreras', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get('/monitoreo/desempeñocarreras' , function(json){
      $('#contenido').empty();
      $('#contenido').hide().append(json.view).fadeIn(400)
      $('#contenido').scrollTop(0);
      var id_facus = [];
      var ids = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < json.facultades.length; i++) {
        id_facus.push(json.facultades[i].id);
        ids.push("tag"+i)
      }

      for (var j = 0; j < id_facus.length; j++) {
        $(".carreras_list_"+j).on('change',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var carrera_id = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
            url: '/monitoreo/desempeñocarreras/'+carrera_id ,
            type: 'post',
          })
          .done(function(vista){
                $("#"+ids[j]).empty();
                $("#"+ids[j]).hide().append(vista.view).fadeIn(400);

          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

imagen:

Solamente se imprime en el primer `div`, independiente de qué lista se haga la consulta. Ej: Si hago la consulta desde la lista "Facultad Humanidades", el resultado es impreso en el `<div>` correspondiente a "Facultad de Ingeniería" y no en el `<div>` de la lista en la que hice la consulta.

[image: Solamente se imprime en el primer div, independiente de que lista se haga al consulta]

Comment: por que no haces  `<select id = "list_{{$i}}" >`

Answer (score 0):

Basandome en lo que dice tu pregunta, es tener un `id` de forma dinamica(por medio de PHP) en `JQuery` , creo que tu pregunta es como obtener un id de un div agregado dinamicamente aqui el ejemplo, al darle click obtendras el `id` suponiendo que con `PHP` lo que hicistes es generar el `HTML`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".tag").click(function(){
  $("#contenido").fadeOut('fast', function() { $(this).remove(); });
  var id_tag = $(this).attr('id');

 $("<div id='contenido'> mi contenido </div>").hide().appendTo(this).fadeIn("slow");

  
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag" id="1">Tag 1</div>
<div class="tag" id="2">Tag 2</div>
<div class="tag" id="3">Tag 3</div>
```

Comment: Hola hice tu sugerencia pero solo me captura el primer id. Deje una imagen en el post principal.

Comment: @DiegoWL en el ejemplo se ve que muestro el id haces algo adicional a el JQuery?

Comment: Adicional no. Solo lo que puse ahi.

Comment: que version de Jquery utilizas?

Comment: jquery version 3.1.1

Comment: acabo de actualzar , es lo que quieres?? @DiegoWL

Comment: No pude hacerlo lamentablemente, no me ha funcionado nada hasta el momento jaja.